# Got a Dell D620 with no OS, would like to use USB to get Ubuntu on it. Where do I start?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, dell

I Just bought a Dell D620 on the cheap and it comes without an OS. Initially I figured I could just download Ubuntu on a USB, plug it in, and boot up Ubuntu, obviously there is more to it.

Where do I begin?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Turn the power on and press F2. You may have to hold it down. When you get to the BIOS screen you'll be looking for boot devices. If your USB is plugged in, it should be on the list. Select the USB, save changes and reboot. If your USB is an ISO image and the BIOS fix worked then it will boot to ubuntu installation.